# UrlMappings in Tomcat container vs. running via grails run-app

Tags: grails, grails3

In Grails 3.3.0, I'm having an issue with getting it to use the UrlMappings that I've defined. For instance, I'm trying to have "/" map to the default controller/action.

This works locally (I've turned on logging for 'org.grails.plugins.web.mapping').

I see this in log:

2017-09-01 18:08:05,254 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder - Attempting to match URI [/] with pattern [500]
2017-09-01 18:08:05,254 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder - Attempting to match URI [/] with pattern [/]
2017-09-01 18:08:05,302 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder - Matched URI [/] with pattern [/], adding to posibilities

...and the default controller/action is what I see.

In the Tomcat container, I see this:

09-01 17:44:35,968 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.grails.webflow.mvc.servlet.GrailsFlowHandlerMapping - Looking up Grails controller for URI [/]
2017-09-01 17:44:36,019 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping@17ef7838] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

but I don't see it attempt to match against "/". Or the 500, for that matter. Any ideas on what else to look for to troubleshoot this?

Comment: It's hard to tell with this much information.
make sure: you've changed embedded tomcat dependency to `provided` before building war and deploying into tomcat, if there is no context path configured in applicaiton.groovy/yml, deployed as ROOT.war in tomcat webapps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the embedded tomcat dependency is set to provided, and the context path is set to the expected value.

Comment: locally there is another difference : the environment set is 'development'. The war you've deployed is maybe in 'production' mode. For instance when you generate the war this the command 'grails war', by default the environment set is production. Then maybe the difference you observe is caused by a difference in your Grails configuration between development and production environment.